# send json message from filebeat to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I would like to send json-formatted messages to logstash via filebeat.

i can filter each key value in json by writing the following in filebeat:

```
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: message
```

However, multi-line could not be processed.
How can I get a multi-line?

And, Can I get rid of the fields that are added to filebeat by default?
I want to remove metadata from filebeat.
I want to receive only the information I send from logstash. Just like in a file.
Is there no way??

```
{"1": "val1" ,"2": "val2" ,"3": "val3\nval3\nval3" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not about multi-line. I think we need more context, however you should look at the json filter plugin documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Your logstash pipeline should look like the following :

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 'xxxx'
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
        # put the terms you want to exclude from your metadata on the "remove_field" array
        remove_field => ["beat","input","prospector","offset"]
    }

}

output {
[...]
}
```

Comment: i are already using filter in logstash. But it still does not work.
`   grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    json{
        source => "message"
    }`

Comment: You can't have both an apache and a json input at the same time. You say that you're sending "json-formatted messages", so you have to remove the grok filter part and keep the json one.